# Parsley Validation & Tabs

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, silverstripe, parsley.js

I have a form on my page on a tab using Foundation-5's tabs.

When i load the page, i get the following error:

`You must bind Parsley on an existing element.`

This I think is because the form is not in the Dom when parsley is invoked because the non-active tabs are display:none

```
$('form.parsley').parsley({ })
```

How can i enable Parsley for my form?

Parsley is currently invoked like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.entwine('ss.zenvalidator', function($) {   
        $('form.parsley').parsley({
             excluded: 'input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], :hidden, .ignore-validation'
        });

        $('.field').entwine({

            getFormField: function() {
                var rtn = this.find('[name='+this.getFieldName()+'], [name="'+this.getFieldName()+'[]"]');
            },

            getFieldName: function() {
                return this.attr('id');
            },

            getFieldValue: function() {
                return this.getFormField().val();
            },

            evaluateEqualTo: function(val) {
                return this.getFieldValue() === val;
            },

            evaluateNotEqualTo: function(val) {
                return this.getFieldValue() !== val;
            },

            evaluateLessThan: function(val) {
                num = parseFloat(val);
                return this.getFieldValue() < num;
            },

            evaluateGreaterThan: function(val) {
                num = parseFloat(val);
                return parseFloat(this.getFieldValue()) > num;
            },

            evaluateContains: function(val) {
                return this.getFieldValue().match(val) !== null;
            },

            evaluateEmpty: function() {
                return $.trim(this.getFieldValue()).length === 0;
            },

            evaluateNotEmpty: function() {
                return !this.evaluateEmpty();
            },

            evaluateChecked: function() {
                return this.getFormField().is(":checked");
            }


        });


        $('.field.validation-logic').entwine({
            onmatch: function () {
                masters = this.getMasters();
                for(m in masters) {
                    this.closest('form').find('#'+masters[m]).addClass("validation-logic-master");
                }
            },

            getLogic: function() {
                return $.trim(this.getFormField().data('validation-logic-eval'));
            },

            parseLogic: function() {
                js = this.getLogic();
                result = eval(js);
                return result;
            },

            getMasters: function() {
                return this.getFormField().data('validation-logic-masters').split(",");
            }

        });


        $('.field.optionset').entwine({

            getFormField: function() {
                f = this._super().filter(":checked");
                return f;
            }

        });


        $('.field.optionset.checkboxset').entwine({

            evaluateHasCheckedOption: function(val) {
                this.find(':checkbox').filter(':checked').each(function() {
                    return $(this).val() === val || $(this).getLabel() === val;
                })
            },

            evaluateHasCheckedAtLeast: function(num) {
                return this.find(':checked').length >= num;
            },

            evaluateHasCheckedLessThan: function(num) {
                return this.find(':checked').length <= num;
            }
        });

        $('.field input[type=checkbox]').entwine({
            getLabel: function() {
                return this.closest('form').find('label[for='+this.attr('id')+']');
            }
        });

        $('.field.validation-logic.validation-logic-validate').entwine({
            testLogic: function() {
                this.getFormField().toggleClass('ignore-validation', this.parseLogic());
            }
        });


        $('.field.validation-logic.validation-logic-exclude').entwine({
            testLogic: function() {
                this.getFormField().toggleClass('ignore-validation', !this.parseLogic());
            }
        });

        $('.field.validation-logic-master :text, .field.validation-logic-master select').entwine({
            onmatch: function() {
                this.closest(".field").notify();
            },

            onchange: function() {
                this.closest(".field").notify();
            }
        });

        $('.field.validation-logic-master :checkbox, .field.validation-logic-master :radio').entwine({
            onmatch: function() {
                this.closest(".field").notify();
            },

            onclick: function() {
                this.closest(".field").notify();
            }
        });

        $('.field.validation-logic-master').entwine({
            Listeners: null,

            notify: function() {
                $.each(this.getListeners(), function() {
                    $(this).testLogic();
                });
            },

            getListeners: function() {
                if(l = this._super()) {
                    return l;
                }
                var self = this;
                var listeners = [];
                this.closest("form").find('.validation-logic').each(function() {
                    masters = $(this).getMasters();
                    for(m in masters) {
                        if(masters[m] == self.attr('id')) {
                            listeners.push($(this));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                this.setListeners(listeners);
                return this.getListeners();
            }
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following should suffice: (untested)

```
$('form.parsley').entwine({
    onmatch: function() {
        $(this).parsley({
            excluded: 'input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], :hidden, .ignore-validation'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That did suffice : )  - for anyone else that comes along and finds this, there was a lot of other things breaking this which i had to eliminate first - eg facebook js, a different version of jquery in the   sites main js file etc. Once those where eliminated & it really was just the tabs breaking parsley this worked great.  thanks!